# Reverse (flip) a 2d array JS

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates/prints out a 2d array like so:

```
["0|0", "0|1", "0|2", "0|3", "0|4"]
["1|0", "1|1", "1|2", "1|3", "1|4"]
["2|0", "2|1", "2|2", "2|3", "2|4"]
["3|0", "3|1", "3|2", "3|3", "3|4"]
["4|0", "4|1", "4|2", "4|3", "4|4"]
```

How can I reverse it so it creates/prints out an array like so:

```
["4|0", "4|1", "4|2", "4|3", "4|4"]
["3|0", "3|1", "3|2", "3|3", "3|4"]
["2|0", "2|1", "2|2", "2|3", "2|4"]
["1|0", "1|1", "1|2", "1|3", "1|4"]
["0|0", "0|1", "0|2", "0|3", "0|4"]
```

Code below:

```
function createGrid(rowCount, columnCount) {
    for (let x = 0; x < rowCount; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < columnCount; y++) {
            cell(x, y); 
        }
    }
}

function cell(x, y) {
    grid[x] = grid[x] || [];
    grid[x][y] = x + "|" + y;
}

var grid = [];
createGrid(5, 5);
```

Comment: [`Array#reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) ...?

Comment: You mean flip each column?

Comment: @JamesWasson That's a better description

Comment: @user172127 Are you sure you're not undermining the point of the exercise by asking someone to solve it for you?

Comment: @Marquizzo then what's the point of a platform like this? I couldn't do it, so I came here for assistance, which was what this platform was designed for, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass along another parameter to `cell` which sets the left side to `rowCount - 1 - x` instead of to `x`:

```js
function createGrid(rowCount, columnCount) {
    for (let x = 0; x < rowCount; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < columnCount; y++) {
            cell(x, y, rowCount); 
        }
    }
}

function cell(x, y, rowCount) {
    grid[x] = grid[x] || [];
    grid[x][y] = (rowCount - 1 - x) + "|" + y;
}

var grid = [];
createGrid(5, 5);
console.log(grid);
```

That's similar to your original code, but a purer and nicer method would be to create the arrays all at once with `Array.from`:

```js
const createGrid = (x, y) => Array.from(
  { length: x },
  (_, i) => (
    Array.from(
      { length: y },
      (_, j) => `${x - 1 - i}|${j}`
    )
  )
);

console.log(createGrid(5, 5));
```

Comment: Or you can reverse the first `for` loop in `createGrid` function (.i.e `for (let x = rowCount -1; x >= 0; x--)`)

Comment: @Ammar no, that won't work, because `cell(x, y)` just fills in `grid[x][y]` with `x + "|" + y` -- it doesn't matter what order you do this in.

Comment: that is strange, a function which mutates something outside, it calles from a function which itself calls a fuchtion with mutating an array outside. a better way is to return an array inside of the first function which may call a joining function or not.

Answer (score 3):

Put the arrays into an array and reverse it.

```
function createGrid(rowCount, columnCount) {
    for (let x = 0; x < rowCount; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < columnCount; y++) {
            cell(x, y);
        }
    }
}

function cell(x, y) {
    grid[x] = grid[x] || [];
    grid[x][y] = x + "|" + y;
}

var grid = [];
createGrid(5, 5);

//Add this code to any code that makes the array of arrays
grid.reverse().forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ '4|0', '4|1', '4|2', '4|3', '4|4' ]
[ '3|0', '3|1', '3|2', '3|3', '3|4' ]
[ '2|0', '2|1', '2|2', '2|3', '2|4' ]
[ '1|0', '1|1', '1|2', '1|3', '1|4' ]
[ '0|0', '0|1', '0|2', '0|3', '0|4' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different implementation using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for demonstration purposes:

```js
const grid = Array.from({length: 5}, (_, x) => Array.from({length: 5}, (_, y) => `${4-x}|${y}`));

// print result
grid.forEach(row => console.log(...row));
```